# juju bootstrap tries to get juju tools from amazon when in a maas enviroment

Tags: juju, maas

anyone knows why....

OptiPlex-320:~$ juju version
1.16.3-precise-amd64

OptiPlex-320:~$ juju bootstrap

WARNING no tools available, attempting to retrieve from https://juju-dist.s3.amazonaws.com/

my environments.yaml is

```
default: maas
environments:
  maas:
        type: maas
        maas-server: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/MAAS/'
        maas-oauth: '3Ey3RueWP2X4asFahJ:CmR3fPYaTBwxhvx8::::sample'
        admin-secret: ''
        authorized-keys-path: /home/xxxxxxx/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: The latest stable release of Juju is 1.18.4 which should download tools from streams.canonical.com.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think downloading from S3 is an issue? In any case as I said, the latest release will download from a Canonical server by default. Note you can always use --upload-tools to avoid this, but it is not recommended.